# How to show $x^3 - x^2 -11x-12$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How can I show that the polynomial $f(x)=x^3 - x^2 -11x-12$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, I've tried Einstein's criterion but it fails. I'm not sure about any other methos I could use to show this.

Comment: It's probably Eisenstein's criterion you mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it were reducible it would have a linear factor, and then an integer solution (observe it is monic). We can check the candidates for integers solutions, which must be divisors of $12$.

Check if $\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4,\pm6,\pm12$ are solutions. If none of them is a solution then it must be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I have a single solution for it, however it isn't in $\mathbb{Q}$. Can I assume that it has a rational solution and arrive at a contradiction somehow

Comment: By Gauss's lemma, if it had a rational solution it would have an integer solution.

Comment: By Gauss' lemma if it is rational then it must be integer.

Comment: This is all for showing that the polynomial is reducible. But my polynomial is irreducible and I want to show why

Comment: @AndrewBrick A polynomial of degree $\;\le 3\;$ over *any* field is **reducible** iff it has at least one root in that field. You're done already with this answer.

Comment: Then how do I show that this polynomial has no rational solutions?

Comment: @AndrewBrick Have you read already **and understood** the above comments?? The answer itself is making use of the rational root theorem for integer polynomials.

Comment: I've just seen Carol's edit, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The polynomial $f(x)$ is irreducible if and only if $f(x+6)$ is irreducible.  In this case
$$f(x+6)=x^3+17x^2+85x+102\ ,$$
which is irreducible by Eisenstein with $p=17$.